# Python Requests using PFX certificate wont work ! - OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines'] - PFX to PEM conversion necessary?

Tags: python, openssl, python-requests, pfx

I've scoured Stack trying to find the answer to this. I basically have a certificate installed and can access the XML file via chrome, but I am trying to pull it directly into python using requests.

I'm simply using

```
response = requests.get(url, cert='C:\\Users\\User\\Cert.pfx')
```

I have not included the url, as it can't be reached for replication without the certificate regardless.

I keep receiving the error

```
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line'), ('SSL 
routines', 'use_certificate_chain_file', 'PEM lib')]
```

I'm using Python 3 on a windows machine. I'm pretty confident the PFX certificate has been exported successfully, but if I do have to convert it to PEM, I am unsure how to do that correctly. Perhaps I do not have to do so, but then I am unsure why I am getting a PEM error. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

from what I saw you can use a custom context manager to do the convertion to pem:

https://gist.github.com/erikbern/756b1d8df2d1487497d29b90e81f8068